# Partial sum of numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, statistics, probability-theory

My TA gave today this question as a nice question to think about. He said its involves standard ideas of Probability theory and numbers.  But, I don't even know how to start.

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be non-negative real numbers. Let $X$ be sum of $k, 1\leq k\leq n$ of them.

Let $r_i, i=1, \ldots, n$ be Bernoulli random variables with probability $P(r_i=1)=p$ and $P(r_i=0)=1-p$.

1). Represent any moment of $X$ in terms of the moments of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_ir_i$, i.e. $E|X|^q$ in terms of $E\left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_ir_i\right|^q$ for $q>1$.

2). Find $p$.

Any help is veery appreciated. I really wanted to understand how to solve it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Bernoulli random variables. Is every $r_i$ $0$ or $1$ independently of the other $r_i$'s, or am I missing something?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the sum $\sum_{1}^{n} x_i r_i$ is randomly choosing, on average, $pn$ of the numbers $x_1,\dots,x_n$, and summing them. Now it depends on how the $x_i$'s are distributed: for instance, in the trivial case where they are all equal, choosing $p=k/n$ will render that sum to be equal, on average, to the sum of $k$ of the $x_i$'s. But as it stands I think that the problem is missing some information.

Comment: I've doubled ckecked with my TA. You are right. Something is missing... I've changed addeted the question. Thank you.

Comment: Th exponent $p$ in 1) is the same $p$ that appears in $P(r_i=1)=p$ ?

Comment: Thank you. Its typo. It suppose to be the $q$-th moment.

Comment: For part 2, it just says "find $p$"... find $p$ such that what? What condition do you need to satisfy with your choice of $p$?

Comment: such $p$ that part 1 is true.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Key to solving this should be the following observations.

1. Expectation is linear. Sum of expectation is expectation of sum. [Note that this isn't obviously or necessarily true when you have an infinite sum.]
2. The Bernoulli $r_i$ are identically distributed. This means that $\mathbb{E}[r_i] = \mathbb{E}[r_1].$
3. The $x_i$ are just numbers. The expectation of $x_i$ is just $x_i$.

I think this should get you there.

Comment: But I am looking for the expectation of the sum of $x_ir_i$ and I don't have that this identically distributed any more...